# TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I changed my code from es5 class prototype representation to es6 class representation. But I am getting error

this is the code before and after migration to es6

es5 syntax

```
function RoutingScreen (context) {
  Object.assign(this, {route} = context)
}

RoutingScreen.prototype.onEnter = function(state) {
  state.scaning = false
  state.status = 'Scan to continue'
  curState = states.init
};
```

es6 syntax

```
class RoutingScreen{
  constructor(context){
    Object.assign(this, {route}= context)
  }

onEnter(state){
    state.scaning = false
    state.status = 'Scan to continue'
    curState = states.init
  }
}
```

I am getting error like this

> TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'scaning'

but es5 code is working properly.

I am using node version 8.1

I don't know what i had done wrong here.

this where i called these method

```
    function setRoute (newRoute) {
        var r = currentRoute()
        console.log('changeRoute from ' + (r?r.route:'""') + ' to ' + newRoute)
        if (r && r.route == newRoute) {
          return true
        }
        if (!r || !r.onExit || r.onExit(state) !== false) {
          stateStack.pop()
        }
        r = newRoute ? pushRoute(newRoute) : currentRoute()
        state.session.route = r.route


        return !r.onEnter || r.onEnter(state)

  }
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `set` method for `scanning` on the `state` Object ? What are you returning from it ?

Comment: function setRoute (newRoute) {
    var r = currentRoute()
    console.log('changeRoute from ' + (r?r.route:'""') + ' to ' + newRoute)
    if (r && r.route == newRoute) {
      return true
    }
    if (!r || !r.onExit || r.onExit(state) !== false) {
      stateStack.pop()
    }
    r = newRoute ? pushRoute(newRoute) : currentRoute()
    state.session.route = r.route
    return !r.onEnter || r.onEnter(state)
  }

state is global state object that is changing in onEnter method

Comment: You've to put the above code between backticks for readability , it's just left to key `1` on your keyboard

Comment: I have added in the post

Comment: This setter will return false in some cases, I assume ...

Comment: The error says the setter returned a value other than true

Comment: which one? method onEnter or setRoute?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152497/discussion-between-malice-and-al-ameen).

Comment: see the `return true` in the example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46273767/965666 the equivalent in your case should resolve this error, for more info see the "Return value" info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set

Answer (score 12):

I was having this same issue in an example of using proxy objects I was going through the JavaScript Ninja book ... when I attempted to write a set method.

```
set: (target, key, value) => {
  target[key] = value;
}
```

This throws a TypeError in strict mode:

> Uncaught TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property

Since it was returning 'falsish', I fixed it by returning true with the method:

```
set: (target, key, value) => {
  target[key] = value;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I think a good practice it to either return the value that has been set, or even the target (better in case the value is false or 0 or any javascript falsy value)